# Using Process.ProcessorAffinity on a system with 32+ logical cores

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to set the processor affinity on a process on a machine that has 16 total physical processor cores, 32 logical. Before, we were using an int but that will overflow when you have 32 logical cores.

Will using a long, instead of an int, when setting the processor affinity still work?

See the code below.

```
 try
 {
    string pathToExe = GetPathToExe( jobType );

    long processorAffinity = DetermineProcessorAffinity();

    Process jobProcess = Process.Start( pathToExe, jobId.ToString() );
    if ( jobProcess != null )
    {
       jobProcess.ProcessorAffinity = new IntPtr( processorAffinity );
    }

 }
```

Comment: Did you test using a long yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [IntPtr documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> The IntPtr type is designed to be an
>   integer whose size is
>   platform-specific. That is, an
>   instance of this type is expected to
>   be 32-bits on 32-bit hardware and
>   operating systems, and 64-bits on
>   64-bit hardware and operating systems.

In other words: It should work on 64 bits systems, but not on 32 bit systems. I guess that's not a problem in your case.

Comment: As a side note I'd like to point out that you don't need to set your project in visual studio to 64 bit. What you do need is a 64 bit operating system. That is to say the IntPtr doesn't use your project settings to determine the bit-ness of the hardware.

Answer (score 4):

Under the hood the `ProcessorAffinity` property will eventually call the Win32 method `SetProcessAffinityMask`.

- [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686223(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686223%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

This method is intended to work with more than 32 processors and this solution should work.

Do be aware though that this approach doesn't work in a 32 bit process.  In a 32 bit process the backing value of an `IntPtr` will still be 32 bits.  The `IntPtr` constructor will silently truncate the `long` value into a `int` value and you`ll never be able to set the affinity more the extra processors.